hawkbit update server maven clean install failed
I was following hawkbit update server installation from source (https://eclipse.dev/hawkbit/gettingstarted/)
But it crashed when building hawkbit core
Can someone help me on what to do next?
ERROR LOGS:
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! :source
[INFO] Compiling 52 source files with javac [debug deprecation release 17] to target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for hawkBit :: Parent 0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] hawkBit :: Parent .................................. SUCCESS [  0.727 s]
[INFO] hawkBit :: Core .................................... FAILURE [  0.108 s]
[INFO] hawkBit :: Core Security ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: Repository .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: Repository :: API ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: Repository :: Core Implementation Support SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: Artifact Repository :: Filesystem ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: Repository :: Test Utilities ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: Repository :: JPA Implementation ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: Security Integration .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: HTTP Security ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: DMF ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: DMF :: API .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: DMF :: RabbitMq Test module ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: DMF :: AMQP 0.9 Implementation .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: REST .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: REST :: Core ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: REST :: DDI API ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: REST :: DDI Resources ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: REST :: Management API .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: REST :: Management Resources ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: Spring Boot Autoconfigure ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: Spring Boot Starters .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: Spring Boot Starter DDI API ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: Spring Boot Starter DMF API ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: Spring Boot Starter Management API ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: Spring Boot Starter ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: Runtime :: Parent ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: Runtime :: Update Server (Monolith) ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: Test Report ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: Runtime :: DDI Server ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: Runtime :: DMF Server ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: Runtime :: Management Server ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkbit-sdk ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: SDK :: Commons .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: Runtime :: Simple UI .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: SDK :: Device SDK ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: SDK :: DMF SDK .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hawkBit :: SDK :: Test / Example ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.171 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-04-26T15:52:48-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project hawkbit-core: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :hawkbit-core


JAVA
openjdk 11.0.22 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.22+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu222.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.22+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu222.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)

OS Ubuntu 22:  uname -a Linux ggbuild1 6.5.0-28-generic #29~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  4 14:39:20 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Maven : mvn -v Apache Maven 3.6.3 Maven home: /usr/share/maven Java version: 11.0.22, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "linux", version: "6.5.0-28-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
I have tried reinstalling maven and java but it seems to not solve the problem
